# Failed to load extension from popup box while running selenium scripts

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, chrome

I get the following popup box when I try to run my selenium script in java:

```
Failed to load extension from:
C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir20432_5430\internal. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.
```

[image]

I have tried `chromeoption` `arguments` I have found in other pages. But none seems to work.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class testClass {

     public static String driverPath = "D:/Selenium/Chrome Driver latest/chromedriver.exe";
     public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("disable-extensions");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

I am forced to handle that popup manually. How do I get rid of it ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @debugger89 No, not yet.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on [chromium bug #639](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=639#c36), try setting `useAutomationExtension` to false.

```
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# the below command does not seem to work

```
options.AddArgument("disable-extensions");
```

So I used AddAdditionalCapability to resolve the pop-up issue

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();            
options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Replace

```
options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
```

in your code by

```
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I still get the same pop up box after replacing that line of code with yours.

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of what you mean by pop-up box?

Comment: I've added the snapshot in the question

Comment: It's not a pop-up, it's an error

Comment: But when I click Ok, the script is executed and works fine.

Comment: Any other suggestions?